# VSCode API Display Language detection

Tags: webview, vscode-api

Want to know is there any API available by which we can identify what display language is set in VSCode?

I tried looking into docs and google but didn't find any answers.

When i am opening webview it is still showing en language even though the VSCode display language is FR.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this should work to get the current language:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

let uiLanguage = vscode.env.language;
console.log(uiLanguage);
```

Comment: Any way of passing this language to webview language? @dario